# Flutter Autocomplete widget completion with accents and event

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, widget

I'm building a screen to recover seed phrase using [BIP39 Mnemonic](https://pub.dev/packages/bip39_mnemonic). This screen contains up to 24 `Autocomplete<String>` widgets it works well with [english wordlist](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt), but completion seems not to work with accents used in [french](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/french.txt), spanish…

[image: émission found] [image: émission not found]

Another concern about getting values ​​from these widgets, using **onSelected** I am updating a data structure but it only works if the user clicks on the drop down word, how to deal with the case where the user writes the complete word without using auto-completion?

Sometime the completion is not very accurate, for example in a list with away, runway, subway and way, if the user input way it still show away, runway, subway before.
[image: non accurate auto-completion]

1. How to deal with accents in auto-completion ?
2. How to handle with a user that don't select words in auto-completion dropdown ?
3. How to correct inaccurate auto-completion ?

PS: my tests are on Flutter Linux app

Sample of code:

```dart
            GridView.count(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                children: List.generate(24, (index) {
                  return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      child: Autocomplete<String>(
                        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                          if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                            return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                          }
                          return widget.language.list.where((String option) {
                            return option
                                .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                          });
                        },
                        onSelected: (String selection) {
                          sentence[index] = selection;
                          print(index.toString() + selection);
                        },
                      ));
                })),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [exaby73](https://github.com/exaby73) : " Using [unicodelookup](https://unicodelookup.com/), the character in your code is actually 2 unicode characters (rendered as one), the letter e (0x65) and the combining acute accent ´ (0x301). While when you type the letter in the app, you're using the single unicode character é (0xE9). "
   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104927#issuecomment-1141140735

**I solved it by [NFKD normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms) the input string using [unorm_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/unorm_dart).**

Code sample

```dart
....  

import 'package:unorm_dart/unorm_dart.dart' as unorm;

....

                      return frenchWordlist.where((String option) {
                        return option.contains(
                            unorm.nfkd(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase())); // NFKD normalize using unorm_dart
                      });
....
```